# How in WordPress include php file after post content

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I make plugin for WordPress, and I want to add content php file to end of post content.

This is my plugin file:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'modlifyContent');

function modlifyContent($content)
{
    global $post;
    $content .= include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'my_plugin_test.php');
    return  $content ;

}
```

but, content php file is added at start of post content.

This is content php file which I want to include to of post content:

```
<div>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true); ?>">Enter</a>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ipsum augue.</span>
</div>
```

How I can include content of php file to the end of post content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'modlifyContent');

function modlifyContent($content)
{
    global $post;
    //output buffer start
    ob_start();
    include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'my_plugin_test.php');
    //delete output buffer and returns its content
    $append = ob_get_clean();
    return  $content. $append;

}
```